# What is a four-orbit rendezvous?

Tags: iss, spacecraft, rendezvous

In a book I'm reading, there is a sentence like this:

> However, such a long rendezvous is cramped, uncomfortable and not
>   the most efficient use of time for astronauts or Mission Control, and so
>   in August 2012 a new ​­four-​­orbit rendezvous profile was attempted,
>   using a Progress cargo vehicle.

My question is: what is a four-orbit rendezvous profile? Does it mean that the spacecraft has to complete 4 orbits right before rendezvous with ISS? And so before 2012 it has to completes more orbits?

Comment: Unless there is some reason to conceal the title of the book you are reading, it's always more helpful and proper to name your quoted source, and in this case the page number.